# Affine open set of spec$A$ is distinguished?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is any affine open subset of spec$A$ necessarily of the form $D(f)$? Why?

Here $D(f):=\{ \mathfrak p  \text{ prime ideal of } A | f \notin\mathfrak p\}$.

Comment: What is $A$?  Any ring, or something more specific?

Comment: @tracing $A$ is a ring.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7153/open-affine-subscheme-of-affine-scheme-which-is-not-principal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E$ be an  elliptic curve, say over $\mathbb C$ , with origin $O$ and let $X=E\setminus \{O\}=\operatorname {Spec} A$ the affine curve obtained by deleting that origin.
Choose $P\in E$ such that for every $n\gt0$ we have  $n[P]-n[O]\neq 0\in \operatorname {Cl}E$, the class group of $E$.
This is equivalent to $P\oplus\cdots\oplus P\neq 0$ ($n$ summands) in the underlying abelian group of $E$, in other words the condition is that $P$  not be a torsion element of that group.
Then I claim that:

> **The affine open subset $U=X\setminus \{P\}\subset X$ cannot be written $U=D(f)$ for any $f\in A$**.

Indeed, if such an $f$ existed it could be seen as a rational function $F\in \operatorname {Rat}E$ with divisor necessarily of the form $\operatorname {Div}(F)=nP-nO\in \operatorname {Div}(E)$.
But this implies for the class $[nP-nO]$ that  $[nP-nO]=n[P]-n[O]=0\in \operatorname {Cl}(E)$, a contradiction with the choice of $P$.